# Migrating DB's from Notes to Sharepoint

Tags: document-migration

We are using the Quest tool.  Having issues in identifying in Notes were the attachments are stored and migrating them with the other attributes.

Comment: Please explain question in detail.... may be with screenshot etc.... this might not help others to understand what issue you are facing..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a third party tool to migrate data to SharePoint you might want to contact them for support.